# HttpRequest and javascript - can you mimic actual browser behavior with regards to javascript with C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, httpwebrequest

I'm posting some form values to a form using HttpWebRequest.  The problem is that the post behaves differently depending on javascript function call results.  Javascript runs on the client browser, so I'm doubting I can get around this problem, but does anyone know a way of mimic-ing a browser's behavior with regard to javascript from C# code?

Alternatively, is there a way for me to manipulate Internet Explorer to get and post values to different URLs from a C# Windows Service?  Can it be done with a WinForms app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can automate browsers from any .NET application using an automation framework:

- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)
- [WatiN](http://watin.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can run Javascript in cscript.exe.  You don't get the browser API, but you can use Javascript libraries, can do AJAX, XMLHTTPRequest, etc.

You can also use a MSHTML control within a C# app to retrieve a web page.  That is effectivedly embedding IE into your app, including running browser-side Javascript.